# Method for release resources in iOS 6.0

Tags: ios, ios6, viewdidunload

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iOS 6 - viewDidUnload migrate to didReceiveMemoryWarning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12674268/ios-6-viewdidunload-migrate-to-didreceivememorywarning)

In iOS 6.0 viewDidUnload: and other something methods has been deprecated. If I need release some resources like UIWebView or network connection, what method should I use? (provided ARC is included) Thanks.

Comment: You might have to use `- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning`.

Comment: ACB, how about if this method called when UIViewController is not released (for example simulate memory warn. on simulator). Then I will destroy non-reducing resources, true?  How I can release my resources only when UIViewController destroyed and unloaded.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/12676743/1730272

Comment: I think I figured it out. I set delegate for UIWebView in Interface Builder and not set him to nil in viewDidLoad: and didReceiveMemoryWarning, I think system on low-level released delegate before webView. Thank you!

Comment: Ok, I will add it as an answer so that you can close this.