# viewDidUnload and didReceiveMemoryWarning Compatibility

Tags: ios

viewDidUnload is not allowed at ios6,so how to Compatibility viewDidUnload and didReceiveMemoryWarning to call.
i need

```
- (void)viewDidUnload{

self.listArr=nil;

[super viewDidUnload];
}  




 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{

[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
float sysVer =[[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];
if (sysVer>= 6.0f){
    if([self isViewLoaded] && !self.view.window){
        self.listArr=nil;

        self.view = nil;
    }
}

 NSLog(@" BrowseComment didReceiveMemoryWarning");
```

}

or only use the follow code at ios5 and ios6

```
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{

[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    if([self isViewLoaded] && !self.view.window){
        self.listArr=nil;

        self.view = nil;
    }


 NSLog(@" BrowseComment didReceiveMemoryWarning");
```

}

Comment: Please refer to this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12674268/ios-6-viewdidunload-migrate-to-didreceivememorywarning][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12674268/ios-6-viewdidunload-migrate-to-didreceivememorywarning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In iOS 6, the **viewWillUnload** and **viewDidUnload** methods of UIViewController are now deprecated. If you were using these methods to release data, use the **didReceiveMemoryWarning** method instead. You can also use this method to release references to the view controller’s view if it is not being used.

The codes currently using in `viewDidUnload` should be moved into  `didReceiveMemoryWarning`. It will work on both iOS5 & iOS6 also. Actually before this change happens the `viewDidUnload` method is get invoked only when application did receive memory warning. So `viewDidUnload` does not have any particular significance. So they deprecate it.

Comment: how to release data at ios5 and ios6

Answer (score 0):

From iOS 6 onwards the `viewDidUnload` and `viewWillUnload` have no role.

So if you need to handle the memory warnings, do it in the `didReceiveMemoryWarning`

Comment: if using ios5,can i do it  in the didReceiveMemoryWarning

Comment: @pengwang: sure you can definitely do it there in iOS 5.