# Deprecation of viewdidUnload in ios 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I dont know why viewDidUnload is deprecated from ios6.Does it mean that xcode will automatically manages the deallocation of objects created and control the memory usage

Comment: If you have a developer account, there's a video session in wwdc 2012 about iOS memory management stating clearly that viewDidUnload is going to be 'dismissed', leaving all the 'emergency' management to be managed in didReceiveMemoryWarning

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that if you not using ARC you need to move objects releasing to `dealloc` method from `viewDidUnload` if you create application only for iOS 6 and higher.

Also look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12676743/1263701)

Comment: You've always needed to do that without ARC, `viewDidUnload` was never a replacement for `dealloc`...