# What is the pair method for viewDidLoad if viewDidUnload is deprecated?

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, viewdidload, viewdidunload

Is it dealloc or which method? If I setup some code in `viewDidLoad`, I want to unistall this setup from the pair method of `viewDidLoad`.. For example `viewDidLoad` & `viewDidDisappear` combo is not always clever combination. And sometimes is better to do the setup from viewDidLoad than from `viewDidAppear` (because that can usually cause flickering)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS6 viewDidUnload Deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12603336/ios6-viewdidunload-deprecated)

Comment: Could you be more specific? What are trying to achieve? May be there is exist workaround without `didUnload`

Answer (score 1):

Starting in iOS 6, views are no longer unloaded by the OS.

*You* can still manually unload your views when they are not needed by doing `self.view = nil;` in your code, but in that case, any code you want to run when the view is unloaded can just be put after that line.